# How to validate if entered text for a column is in Upper Case

Tags: column, validation

I need to validate if the text entered in a text column is written in UPPER CASE.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Is this in code? in javascript? as a field validator? as a timer job?  as an event handler?  In an Infopath form?

Comment: would it be one word or series of words (sentence) and are numerals included ?

Comment: Sorry, I need to validate if a column single line of text type is filled in UPPER case. i.e. if somebody writes elap this should be validated to be ELAP. i guess this would be using a column validator field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I wanted to validate a 4 to 5 field Identifier named IS. The IS field should contain 4 to 5 Upper case letters. I did it using ASCII code. Sum must return a value of 12. lower case letters sum less than 12, in that case sentence returns false:

=IF(((CODE(MID(IS,1,1))>47)+(CODE(MID(IS,1,1))<58)+(CODE(MID(IS,1,1))>64)+(CODE(MID(IS,1,1))<91)+(CODE(MID(IS,2,1))>47)+(CODE(MID(IS,2,1))<58)+(CODE(MID(IS,2,1))>64)+(CODE(MID(IS,2,1))<91)+(CODE(MID(IS,3,1))>47)+(CODE(MID(IS,3,1))<58)+(CODE(MID(IS,3,1))>64)+(CODE(MID(IS,3,1))<91)+(CODE(MID(IS,4,1))>47)+(CODE(MID(IS,4,1))<58)+(CODE(MID(IS,4,1))>64)+(CODE(MID(IS,4,1))<91))=12,TRUE,FALSE)

The formula verifies if the letters are between A~Z excluding from a~z,0~9.

i.e. Writing in the IS field the identifier "elap" {8} returns false
     Writing "ELAP" {12} returns True

In this case this worked just fine, but i'm still open to improvements. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need something similar to this - http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2011/12/how-to-validate-strict-text-formats-in-sharepoint-2010/

You'll find examples on how to  validate on upper case strings by googling.

Ricky Spears has written good blogs about how to create validation regexs for Column Validation - [Read more here](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.dk/2012/03/series-of-posts-on-column-validation-in.html)